# React "href" and "to" property in link tags

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am aware the difference between the two, but I can't really think of why I would use "href" instead of "to". Are there any benefits in using either or, if so an explanation or an example would be great. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you referring to `to` and `href` as it relates to the props you pass to `<Link />` component of react-router?

Answer (score 0):

Href is useful when you want to navigate to another host.
The to prop in the link component is only to a different route in the same host.